# ErrorException: ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No error in <queue_path/queue_name.php>

Tags: php, laravel, archive

I am using ZipArchive for making zip file and adding .csv file to archive in Laravel. My code worked in Controller but doesnt work inside laravel queue.

```
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $zip->open("documents/Name.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE); 
            $path = "documents/NAME.zip";
            $zip->addFile($CSVFilePath, 'a.csv');    
            $zip->close();
```

Comment: I met the same error with this, is there any solution?

Comment: problem was with path:
 $zip = new ZipArchive();
 $zip->open(public_path("/{$name}.zip"), ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);